# How to Query an XML-containing Clob for nodes with PL-SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, t-sql, plsql

In T-SQL I'm doing this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ps_GetAuditUpdatesRequired]
@AuditXML xml
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT 
    doc.col.value('@id', 'int') AS id
FROM  
    @AuditXML.nodes('/rths/rth') AS doc(col)
WHERE (
  -- Get anything needs to be deleted and does exist in the database already
  doc.col.value('@method', 'nvarchar(16)') = 'DELETE' AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM audits_ WHERE doc.col.value('@id', 'int') = audits_.Id_RetinaId ) OR
  -- Get anything that is not set to be deleted and does not already exist with a newer version
  doc.col.value('@method', 'nvarchar(16)') != 'DELETE' AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM audits_ WHERE doc.col.value('@id', 'int') = audits_.Id_RetinaId AND doc.col.value('@versionSerial', 'int' ) <= audits_.nl_VersionSerial)
  )

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

How can I do this in oracle?
Note: The AuditXML parameter will be a CLOB in the Oracle version.

Comment: Can you add a sample XML doc and other data, and what you expect to happen?

Comment: Can you give the XPath for the element/attribute you want to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing you need [an XMLTable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB1700) to extract the node attributes as relational data; you can then use the columns generated from that in your `where` clause:

```sql
SELECT doc.id
FROM XMLTable('/rths/rth'
  PASSING XMLType(:auditXML)
  COLUMNS id NUMBER PATH '@id',
    method NVARCHAR2(16) PATH '@method',
    versionSerial NUMBER PATH '@versionSerial'
) doc
WHERE (
  -- Get anything needs to be deleted and does exist in the database already
  doc.method = 'DELETE' AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM audits_
    WHERE doc.id = audits_.Id_RetinaId
)
OR (
  -- Get anything that is not set to be deleted and does not already exist with a newer version
  doc.method != 'DELETE' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM audits_
    WHERE doc.id = audits_.Id_RetinaId
    AND doc.versionSerial <= audits_.nl_VersionSerial)
  )
)
```

I've use `:auditXML` as a bind variable, but you can pass in a table column or a string literal - though the latter is limited to 4K in plain SQL (up to 12c).

An Oracle procedure can't return the result of a query quite you can in T-SQL. In a procedure the query would have to select *into* something, but depending on how you're using it, you might actually want a pipelined table function and a cursor loop to pipe the rows out, or a function that returns a ref cursor (or a procedure that has a ref cursor OUT parameter).

Comment: This is a beautiful thing man. I've got to use a string literal. I should be good because I'm running 12 c though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT id
FROM   (
  SELECT EXTRACTVALUE( column_value, '/rth/@method' ) AS method,
         EXTRACTVALUE( column_value, '/rth/@id' ) AS id,
         EXTRACTVALUE( column_value, '/rth/@versionSerial' ) AS serial
  FROM   TABLE(
           XMLSequence(
             EXTRACT( XMLType( auditXml ), '/rths/rth' )
           )
         )
) x
WHERE  (
      method = 'DELETE'
  AND EXISTS( SELECT 1
              FROM   audits_ a
              WHERE  x.id = a.Id_RetinaId )
)
OR
(
      ( method IS NULL OR method <> 'DELETE' )
  AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                  FROM   audits_ a
                  WHERE  x.id = a.Id_RetinaId
                  AND    x.serial <= a.nl_VersionSerial )
);
```

Comment: This works (of course) but [extract](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions060.htm) and [extractvalue](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions061.htm) are deprecated.